# Kivy on raspberry pi touchscreen not recognizing touch input

Tags: touchscreen

I have kivy installed on a raspberry pi 3B with the official 7" touchscreen attached. The touchscreen its self works perfectly and touch input is working as expected in the desktop environment.

I can run code to show a kivy app and it displays fine but when I touch the touchscreen I get the following error in the terminal:

'''
INFO: The key you just pressed is not recognized by SDL. To help get this fixed,                                              please report this to the SDL forums/mailing list  EVDEV KeyCode 330
'''

This happens on both pressing the display and lifting off. I have tried executing the app through both the CLI and through a terminal in the desktop environment. Nothing else is installed on the raspberry pi apart from the requirements for kivy. I have tried adding these three lines to ~/.kivy/config.ini as suggested elsewhere but it makes no difference.

'''
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
'''

How can I get the touchscreen to apply my touch inputs correctly in my kivy app?

Edit:
Contents of the file at ~/.kivy/config.ini

"""
[kivy]
keyboard_repeat_delay = 300
keyboard_repeat_rate = 30
log_dir = logs
log_enable = 1
log_level = info
log_name = kivy_%y-%m-%d_%_.txt
window_icon =
keyboard_mode =
keyboard_layout = qwerty
desktop = 1
exit_on_escape = 1
pause_on_minimize = 0
kivy_clock = default
default_font = ['Roboto', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-I$
log_maxfiles = 100
window_shape = data/images/defaultshape.png
config_version = 21

[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 0
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 800
resizable = 1
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0

[input]
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput

[postproc]
double_tap_distance = 20
double_tap_time = 250
ignore = []
jitter_distance = 0
jitter_ignore_devices = mouse,mactouch,
retain_distance = 50
retain_time = 0
triple_tap_distance = 20
triple_tap_time = 375

[widgets]
scroll_timeout = 250
scroll_distance = 20
scroll_friction = 1.
scroll_stoptime = 300
scroll_moves = 5

[modules]

[network]
useragent = curl
"""

Edit2: Python file being run:
Taken from kivy documentation at https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html

```py
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: the actual documentation for native display is here: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-rpi.html#using-official-rpi-touch-display - are you editing the right `.ini` file?

Comment: I followed the instructions there, had no effect.

Comment: can you show the content of the ini file?

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: And then you reboot and nothing works right?

Comment: The program runs correctly, displaying a label with kivy on screen but touching the screen generates the error from the main post.

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer to my own question after some experimentation. It seems that when connecting to the raspberry pi via ssh, the touchscreen was sending strange event codes that SDL in kivy wasn't able to process but that raspian was. The issue can be fixed by not connecting to the rasperry pi by ssh.